# Why can't a group member create a file in a directory with 760 permissions?

Tags: permissions, directory

I have an account with secondary group membership in a group that owns a directory.  The directory is chmod 760, which should allow writing to the directory, but not listing it.  However, this is not allowed.  Can somebody explain why?

Rationale: mostly academic; trying to understand permissions in detail.  I recognize that I could make the permissions 770 and allow this; I'm not an idiot (at least I don't think so).  I just want to understand what write permissions actually mean for a directory, if not file creation.

Code example:

```
powerdave@dhirsch-centos:/tmp >groups
powerdave wheel share
powerdave@dhirsch-centos:/tmp >ls -alh
total 124K
drwxrwxrwt.  5 root      root      4.0K Feb 23 15:08 ./
dr-xr-xr-x. 23 root      root      4.0K Feb 23 14:57 ../
drwxrw----.  2 guest     share     4.0K Feb 23 14:52 test/
powerdave@dhirsch-centos:/tmp >touch test/file
touch: cannot touch `test/file': Permission denied
```

Comment: So, after reading that "duplicate", the question remains: is there any meaning to +w on a directory if +x is required for all the writing operations?

Answer (score 2):

- `r` allows listing — just the names.
- `w` deleting and adding.
- `t` prevents deleting — if you don't own it.
- `x` allows navigation — stating a file or directory: reading meta data, reading meta-data is needed to be able to access, add or delete a file within the directory.

**If you can not navigate, then you can not delete, add, or anything else.**

Comment: So is there any useful use of a directory with no `x`? Maybe to taunt: look at all these files, that you can no access.

Comment: The problem I'm seeing is this part: "w deleting and adding".  Adding doesn't seem to actually be true!  I can't add a new file - see original post.

Comment: Edited answer to be clearer.